# Health Insurance for schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, paperwork

Applying for schengen visa requires Health insurance policy with a minimum coverage of €30,000 for emergency hospital and repatriation expenses.

I will be visiting Italy with my mother and father for tourism purposes.

So I want to ask if each one of us is required to have a Health insurance? Is it really necessary or optional?

i'm asking  because €30,000 seems to be a large amount for us.

Comment: A day in a hospital costs at least €1000-2000 (not to the patient but to the state/healthcare system/insurer), that's what the €30000 are there to cover. A serious accident can easily lead to a bill like that and in Europe you would in any case receive care and would generally not be expected to pay for it yourself. Mandatory insurance is there so that the healthcare institutions have someone to turn to to recover the money.

Answer (score 7):

For your first question, yes, each traveller needs a policy that complies with the regulations...

> ...proof of sufficient medical coverage will be necessary at the time of
>   the visa application. Medical insurance requirements for the Schengen
>   visa are:
>
> - Minimum coverage shall be EUR €30 000 (equivalent to $50,000 USD)
> - Cover must be valid within the Schengen region and for the full    duration of stay
> - Cover any expenses which might arise in connection with repatriation    for medical reasons, urgent medical attention and/or
>     emergency    hospital treatment or death

You will not be able to successfully apply for a Schengen visa without proof.

For your implicit question about EUR 30,000, this is the *policy coverage amount*.  To receive this coverage you would pay the *premium amount*.  You didn't include the length of your stay in Italy, but *premiums* generally start at EUR 30 - EUR 45 for the minimum coverage and increase according to any additional options you select.  You do not have to put up EUR 30,000.

The [price floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_floor) for these policies is set in the competitive market place, but it's reasonable to expect to pay a minimum of around EUR 30, even for a trip of 7 - 10 days.  You need to enter personal details in order to receive a bookable quote, so a precise answer can be given only by a provider.

You acquire a policy (one for each person) using any of the myriads of providers and then print out the policies and enclose them with your Schengen application.  To locate some providers you can search Google with the keywords: '`Schengen Health Insurance`' (or a suitable translation of it).

Finally, the controlling reference for your question (i.e., the regulation itself) is at [Travel Medical Insurance](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810)...

Comment: I will be staying for no more than 7-10 day.. wats to total amount that i need to pay per person?

Comment: @SurajBhawal, answer amended

Comment: @SurajBhawal You *plan* to stay for no more than 7-10 days. I hope you don't find yourself in hospital with a serious illness but, if you do, you could be there a lot longer than ten days.

Answer (score 2):

Usually international credit cards like [Mastercard](https://www.aigtravelguard.net/mastercard/Default.aspx?IdLanguage=1&mod=faq) provide a Schengen Letter (covering up to 30k euros in medical assistance, if needed) if you buy tour travel tickets with it, or using it's reward points. I know visa credit card also provides such a benefit, but I'm not able to find an english language online reference right now.

If you bought your tickets using a credit card, you're probably covered and it won't cost you anything else.